# Why is Chrome ignoring my CSS selector?

Tags: css, google-chrome

In the following page http://ada.kiexpro.com/test2/map.html
 I added:

```
white-space: normal;
```

to wrap the copyright text that is coming our from the Google map API.
It works in FF and IE but Chrome seems to ignore the CSS selector:

global.css:

```
#cm_map span {
white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has an anonymous div with inline styles surrounding the copyright content.  Only hook I can see is that it's a sibling of the "logocontrol" div.  To override, try something like the following:

```
#cm_map #logocontrol + div[style] {
    left: auto !important;
    line-height: 13px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 6px !important;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Not thoroughly tested but something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

This may also be a bug in Chrome: `white-space normal !important` doesn't override `nowrap`.

[image]

I've reported this bug at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89573, but based on how they have been [completely ignoring a more important issue since 2009](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23440), I have little hope of this being fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of chrome ignoring the important.  This time its on the position.  Unclicking the "position: relative" does bring the absolute into the picture.  So the style is valid.

[image]